# How to make responsive 3 image which has different scale?

Tags: html, css

I'm working in Wordpress and i need to insert 3 image in a row.
I'm using default editor because of my client ask that.

Insert the 3 image html for the page and then give this a little CSS with simple CSS plugin :

It's okay, the 3 image appear in a row, which has 170px height, but when i open this in mobile or tablet the scale isn't responsive.
I try to make container which has 170px height, and put the image them but wasn't working. I try to make `@media` query but that wasn't work.

Anyone can help me ?
I want if these 3 picture is got ca. 170px and being responsive.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tanfolyam-kepek {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 170px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box">
  <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc1.jpg"><img class="tanfolyam-kepek" src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc1-226x300.jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
<a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc2.jpg"><img class="tanfolyam-kepek" src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc2-300x300.jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc3.jpg"><img class="tanfolyam-kepek"src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc3-300x243.jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: fisrt, fix your html, use some tool to validate it, there's an `<a>` with two `href` properties

Comment: Thanks you, it's happened, but not the actually answer for my problem

Comment: If you want responsive, don't use absolute units such as "px".  Use relative units such as "%" or "vw" when visual layout is important, and "em" when visual detail is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Responsive images on a row. Verttical **and** horizontal alignment. No use of clearfix. Cross browser.

```
<div class="box-container">
  <div class="box">
    <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc1.jpg">
      <img class="tanfolyam-kepek" src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc1-226x300.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc2.jpg">
      <img class="tanfolyam-kepek" src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc2-300x300.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
    <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc3.jpg">
      <img class="tanfolyam-kepek"src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc3-300x243.jpg" alt=""/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

with css

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.box-container {
  height: 170px; /* height you asked for */
  outline: thin dotted grey; /* this outline for test only */
}
@media (max-width: 575.9px) {
  .box-container {
    height: ...px; /* for mobile, for example 140px */
  }
}
.box {
  float: left;
  width: 33.333%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center; /* horizontal alignment */
}
.box a {
  display: block;
  /* 5 lines below for vertical alignment */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.box img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto; /* responsive image */
  max-height: 170px; /* no overflow */
  border: 10px solid #fff; /* border used as padding */
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the long answer, and i'm so sorry to say this isn't work.
I try to show you how this look like: https://imgur.com/wbAght6
But so close

Comment: Maybe there is some other css that gives this html extra styling and then breaking down this solution. In a clean page it is working fine. Ofcourse yuou have to remove the `outline: ….` line (for testing only).

Comment: Added the @media for less height on mobile. Because the images are **responsive** it is better to re-dimension the images.

Answer (score 0):

you can use bootstrap grid to make your images responsive. all you have to do is

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4>
        //your image here
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4>
        //your image here
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-4>
        //your image here
    </div>
</div>
```

And avoid using `px` to specify the size since it is not responsive. Use `vh` and `vw` which stand for viewport height and viewport width respectively

Comment: Bootstrap will work in wordpress without any script in head or plugin ? Thank you!

Comment: yes, you just have to use this '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">' between your head tags

Comment: in wordpress where shoud i use this ? sorry for stupid question

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not familiar with wordpress but, do you see a <head> tag in your html file right in the beginning. it's around where you set your title .

Comment: that's my problem in wordpress you could use pages to make content, but in pages you can't see head section. just the body

Comment: https://community.swiftype.com/t/where-do-i-add-meta-tags-for-my-wordpress-site/99 may be this would help it says you could get the head tag

Comment: can you please mark my answer correct if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

```
   .box{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 31.3%;
        height: 200px;
        text-align: center;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 20px 0;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    .box img{
        vertical-align: middle;
        display: inline-block;
        height: 100%;
        max-width: none;
        width: auto;
                }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can have something like this for have always tree picters in a row.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.tanfolyam-kepek {
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 170px;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="box">
  <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc1.jpg"><img class="tanfolyam-kepek" src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc1-226x300.jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
<a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc2.jpg"><img class="tanfolyam-kepek" src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc2-300x300.jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
  <div class="box">
  <a href="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc3.jpg"><img class="tanfolyam-kepek"src="https://ezoakademia.hu/wp-content/uploads/2018/12/rozsakvarc3-300x243.jpg" alt=""/></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in which way it turns the image responsive? It is now cutting parts of the images

Comment: it's responsive because he can hold the 170px height, and it's compatible with all the screens